# Installing magento 2 with magento-vagrant failing

Tags: git, magento, github, vagrant, magento2

I am trying to install magento 2 on my PC running Windows 7 , with the help of magento-vagrant ( https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers )

At the step where is says to enter 'bash init_project.sh' I get the following errors:

> [2017-04-01 16:06:14] STATUS: Checking requirements [/w/projets/shoptest.dev/vagrant-magento/scripts/host/check_requirements.sh]]
>   [2017-04-01 16:06:14] STATUS: Installing missing vagrant plugins [init_project.sh]]
>   [2017-04-01 16:06:16] STATUS: Generating random IP address, and host name to prevent collisions (if no custom values specified) [init_project.sh]]
>   [2017-04-01 16:06:17] STATUS: Configuring git for Windows host [init_project.sh]]
>   [2017-04-01 16:06:18] STATUS: Checking out CE repository [init_project.sh]]
>   [2017-04-01 16:06:20] ERROR: Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists. [Unknown source file]] error: Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I have checked that my C:/users/username/.ssh folder has the public keys : correct

I have checked that when I run "ssh-add -l" I have an output of various numbers and letters mexed together. Correct.

I have added the SSH key to the ssh agentby running "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa" Correct, done.

I have copied the key to paste it in my "settings > ssh and pgp keys " category, in the SSH key field, on GitHub.com. Done.

The key icon inside my githubt account turned green and the message:

> "Last used within the last day"

appeared after doing `bash init_project.sh`

What should I do ? I'm lost and don't know much about github and ssh in general. Just followed the steps in the tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't finished your git set-up, you have to configure the git client with your git username, and email:

```
    $ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
    $ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

More details and additional git info at:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having the error message showing. I have now added my username and email, when I check my settings, both have been setup. But I'm still stuck.

Comment: Wow ok. I was using the wrong command-line window to make it happen. I was in the WIndows cmd window. Using Git Bash now, and apparently it  seems to make progress, as it's now on "checking out CE repository". Fail and learn right ? Anyway, thanks for the help Steve.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently successfully install magento 2 (latest version 2.16) on vagrant  and managed to solve a number of issues due to dependency and publickeys. To help anyone who might have similar issues, i have created a github project that puts up the vagrant file and instruction on how to install magento 2 with vagrant on windows (tested on win10, not sure win7 but should work as well):

https://github.com/chen0040/vagrant-magento-2.16

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your public key to GitHub?

In [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io) enter `clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to copy your public key to the clipboard, then go to https://github.com/settings/keys and create a new key, and paste it in there.

Also try running `bash init_project.sh` from Git Bash, running as administrator.